# Removing Google Sign in Popups using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

So, I am using selenium to take screenshots of reddit posts. The way it works is that I resize the screen to fit a mobile device, then take the screenshots using the firefox webdriver. The thing is in some cases, the google sign-in popup blocks the screenshots of the posts and causes an error. Is there any way I can fix this I already tried doing this:

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.headless = False
options.mobile_options = False
options.set_preference("privacy.popups.disable_from_plugins", 3)
```

I tried disabling any popups but it still shows up, anything I can do to block this.